# Android Sugar ORM - Custom/prepopulated database in custom SD path

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, sugarorm

I am using Sugar ORM in my Android application. I have managed to save/read data to/from the database successfully. Now I am in the need to get the created database and check some info for debugging etc. I might also need to use a prepopulated db the first time.

How can this be done in Sugar ORM? I can't find anything in the documentation.

If it cannot be done, Please propose any other easy-to-use ORM that has this ability. (Don't tell me OrmLite, it is not easy to use such as sugar orm)

Answer (score 1):

I see you ask this quite a while ago but I am just finding it.

You can connect adb (Android Debug Bridge) to your device and open an adb shell.

Then in this shell navigate the shell to the database directory and use the SQLite3 command to access the database.

It works quite well in Android studio with the emulator.  I have not tried it with other environments yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it using Sugar ORM right now. There is already an issue to pre-populate data using the migration script, see https://github.com/satyan/sugar/issues/87.

Another quite similar ORM to use would be DBFlow which is also very easy to use.(https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow). I just made a POC using a prepackaged database which worked fine. See https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/blob/master/usage/DBStructure.md for more details how to do that.

Edit: Also check out ActiveAndroid which seems to be very similar to Sugar ORM and also supports pre-populated databases (https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid).